# How do I use autofac to resolve a WCF Data Service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf-data-services, autofac

I am creating a WCF Data Service using the [WCF Data Services Toolkit](http://wcfdstoolkit.codeplex.com/) and its whitepaper [Building OData Services on Top of Existing APIs](http://wcfdstoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/60614#DownloadId=206728). The service is being added to an existing MVC 3 website that is already configured to use the AutofacDependencyResolver. The code provided in the whitepaper for exposing the service is:

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{ 
  var factory = new DataServiceHostFactory();
  var serviceRoute = new ServiceRoute("odata", factory, typeof(CrmODataService));
  serviceRoute.Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary { { "serviceType", "odata" } };
  serviceRoute.Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary { { "serviceType", "odata" } };
  RouteTable.Routes.Add("odata", serviceRoute);
  ...
}
```

Is there a simple way to modify this to resolve the service via Autofac or do I need to implement my own ServiceHostFactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{
  var factory = new AutofacWebServiceHostFactory();
  var serviceRoute = new ServiceRoute("odata", factory, typeof(CrmODataService));
  serviceRoute.Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary { { "serviceType", "odata" } };
  serviceRoute.Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary { { "serviceType", "odata" } };
  RouteTable.Routes.Add("odata", serviceRoute);
  ...
}
```

And elsewhere don't forget to set

```
AutofacWebServiceHostFactory.Container = container;
```